# Al poner en el htaccess la directiva option- indexes . Lo podre ver?

Tags: php

Quiero que no se vea el arbol directorio dese el navegador, mi web.
 Es por eso que creare el htaccess con    option-indexes. 
 Mi pregunta es:

yo los voy a ver cuando quiero.. entrando a mi cpanel verdad?

gracias a los que contesten!!

Answer (score 1):

Si defines `Option -Indexes` sólo sirve para decirle al servidor Apache que no liste el directorio cuando no encuentre un archivo de índice (definidos como `Index`, normalmente son `index.html` e `index.php`).

Si tu Cpanel tiene permiso de lectura en el directorio podrá listarlo sin problema, ya que no tiene nada que ver con el listado que realiza Apache si no encuentra archivo que servir.

Answer (score 0):

Sí, tendrás acceso desde cPanel y ftp. Una buena costumbre aparte de configurar el .htaccess es tener siempre un index.html o index.php en cada directorio o subdirectorio, aunque el index no contenga nada

por costumbre yo pongo un index.php que dice:

```
<?php header( 'Location: /' );
```

así nada mas, sin ni cerrar con ?>